# Question about quadratic convergence on Newton-Raphson method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

> $\textbf{Theorem 1}$
> Let $p$ be a solution of the equation $x = g(x)$. Suppose that
> $g'(p)=0$ and $g''$ is continuous with $|g''(x)| < M$ on an open
> interval $I$ containing $p$. Then, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such
> that for $p_0 \in [p - \delta, p + \delta]$, the sequence defined by
> $p_n = g(p_{n-1})$, when $n \ge 1$, converges at least quadratically
> to p.

I want to prove that Newton-Raphson method converges quadratically when I have a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}, f(a)f(b)<0,f\in C^2([a,b]), \exists x^* \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(x^*) = 0$ and $f'(x^*) \ne 0$. I showed that with this conditions $\exists \delta_0 > 0$ s.t. $\forall x_0 \in [x^* - \delta_0, x^* + \delta_0]$ the sequence $x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}, n\ge1$ have order of convergence at least linear.

Now... How I can use the above theorem to show that order of convergence is at least quadratic? Because if I take the function $\phi(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, $\phi$ is $C^1([a,b])$ and I don't know how to show that $|\phi''(x)| < M$ on an open interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Taylor's formula to get
$$
f(x^*) = f(x_n) + f'(x_n)(x^* - x_n) + \frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2!}(x^*-x_n)^2 
$$

If you divide by $f'(x_n)$ and note that $f(x^*)=0$, you get
$$
\left|x^* -x_n + \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\right| =\left|\frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2 f'(x_n)}\right|(x^*-x_n)^2 
$$
i.e.
$$
|x^*-x_{n+1}| = \left|\frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2 f'(x_n)}\right|(x^*-x_n)^2
$$

Comment: Oh. And by continuity of $f''$ on bounded interval implies that $f''$ is bounded on that interval, so $\exists M>0$ s.t $|f''(\xi_n)| \le M$. It's correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, a detail that is not on the statement of the result is that the convergence is being assumed: If the sequence $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to some $x^*$, $g(x^*)=0$ and the regularity assumptions hold, then the convergence is at least quadratic.